# cmake find_package(Boost) selecting the PATH

Tags: boost, cmake

I recently installed an upgraded version of Boost version (1.71) for a project in usr/local whereas I have the older working version as part of my SDK in `${CUSTOMPATH}`

Due to some bugs I need to go back to my older boost without uninstalling any of my setup. I tried the following experiment to switch my Boost location, however  it doesn't help. Any pointers what I am doing wrong? Is there a workaround without removing the upgraded boost

**CMAKE SNIPPET**

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "${CUSTOMPATH}/usr/local/include" )
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "${CUSTOMPATH}/usr/local/include" )
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "${CUSTOMPATH}/usr/local/libs" )
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem )

message("Boost include dirs: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("Boost libs: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
```

**output**

> Found Boost: /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.71.0") found components:  filesystem program_options system chrono timer
>
> Boost include dirs: /usr/local/include
>
> Boost libs: Boost::filesystem

Comment: What if you specify the version you want, e.g. `find_package(Boost 1.61.0 EXACT ...)`?

Comment: After successful call, results of `find_package` are **cached**. Have you removed the cache before new attempt?

Comment: yes I cleaned up the entire cmake folder, doesn't help...

Comment: @JohnZwinck I am trying not to hard code the version as I would update the CUSTOMPATH based on SDK

Comment: @DennisNinj: Understood.  Still, try it and let us know if it works or not.

Comment: yes EXACT version works, thanks for the alternate solution, do you have any pointers for the above code?